# Android emulator unable to send data to remote server using flask

Tags: android

I have been receiving Not Found
"The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." When i run my server.
My github can be found at this website https://github.com/2100723/AndroidEmulator

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'C:\\Users\\leech\\Desktop\\University\\year2-tri2\\2207\\calllogs\\uploads'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = {'txt', 'csv'}

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_call_logs():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['call_log']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'status': 'failed'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'Invalid request method'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Are you running the flask server on your host desktop, the same one as your emulator? What URL are you using from the emulator to access this server?

Comment: yes i am running the one similar to my emulator

Comment: I do not even need to run my emulator to see whether there is an error or not. Because running my flask alone does not allow me to connect to the remote server. so the issue is from flask.